# Batch file to evaluate the free space of my local drive?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I'm looking for a batch file to evaluate the free space of my local drive.

For example I want to code a batch file to know whether the free space is greater than 300 GB or not. So I found out my free space is 45 GB using

> wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype=3 get caption,size,FreeSpace

But when I compare it with 300 GB, it shows that 45 is greater than 300.

Apparently this batch file program calculates it as a string?

Please help me find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, post you current script.

Comment: you missed a `where`

Comment: my fault, edited in @Stephan

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to incorporate the 300 GiB, *(322122547200 bytes)*, size as a query filter:

```dos
WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='3' And FreeSpace>'322122547200'" Get Caption,Size,FreeSpace
```

Note: You may additionally wish to use the following instead:

- 300000000000 *(300 GB to bytes)*

Comment: GB = 1000³, GiB = 1024³. Users's choice, which value to take.

Comment: …added note to answer